# Optimal algorithm to check which vertices in a set of polygons can be connected to a point without overlap

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a set of polygons described by their vertices. My question is, given a certain vertex, how can I find the vertices of all the polygons to which I can draw a line segment from the given vertex without overlapping the polygons.
Is it possible to do in less than O(n^2)?

Comment: Every line segment connecting any pair of points of the polygon is totally "inside" the polygon.

Comment: Maybe look at "separating planes" - used in collision detection.

Comment: @Beta finding a convex hull can be done in `n log n` time, and finding the remaining nodes not in the convex hull shouldn't be too hard, except for the overlapping convex hulls.

Comment: I feel like there's an average `O(n log n)` solution where you insert all nodes into a slightly augmented quad tree, then for each node, find the angles from its neighbors to form an circle segment. Use that with the quad tree to find nodes in the appropriate region of space. When you find one, check its neighbors to see if it's a hit or a wall (each node knows which side of it is the inside, e.g. ccw double-linked list).

Comment: Transfrom the vertices to polar coordinates with the point in the origin. Then you can process the polygons easily by distance to the point and you only have to check against edges from closer vertices of other polygons, for a single polygon you can start with the 2 closest points, they have to be visible (unless obstructed by a closer polygon), if you go through the rest of the points now, you can keep track of the max angle in both directions, everytime it gets bigger the point is visible.

Comment: Ahaha I was in bed last night and thought of that:p Will try and make an answer when I have it working.